# $http conditional response transforms

Tags: angularjs

I've spent a long time googling on this today and I've found several places where people have asked the same question but never quite got a response.

When I want to use $http in angular to fetch (when successful) a big zip file, pdf, or image, I set request.responseType = "arraybuffer" to get it as a bag o' bits.

The issue is when it's **not** successful.  If I get a 500, whatever error information there was is now just a bag o' bits, which is not nice for the user.

The question is how to make a $http get that processes the results differently depending on whether the request was successful or not.

I came across some StackOflow/github posts with the same question.  They pointed out that the httpInterceptor stuff was **pre-** processing on the request but **post-** processing on the response, and that the transform stuff got in before the response handlers (so the result was already transformed).  I found the github thread where status was added to the param list for the transform function, but that still left you implementing all the other behaviors yourself.

I tried the following and it worked, but it leaves a bad taste in my mouth.  The basic idea was to use the pre- nature of the interceptor for requests to wrap the default response transform in conditional logic as follows

```
/* httpInterceptor.request */
request: function (config) {
    if (config.responseType == 'arraybuffer')
    {
        config.responseType = "";
        config.transformResponse = conditionalArrayBufferTransform(config);
    }
    return config || $q.when(config);
},
....
function conditionalArrayBufferTransform(config)
{
    var defaults = config.transformResponse;
    defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? angular.copy(defaults) : [defaults];

    var oldFunc = defaults[0];  // wrap the lead transform (whatever it is) with a closure that will set the responseType back if not an error
    defaults[0] = function (data, headerGetter, status)
    {
        if (status != 500)
        {
            config.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        }
        return  (typeof oldFunc === "function") ? oldFunc(data, headerGetter, status) : data;
    }
    return defaults;
}
```

So to my surprise, that produced the desired results - a bag o' bits if the request was successful and a "leave the response alone" if it wasn't.  But it feels kind of kludgy.

Does anyone have a more canonical suggestion?  The signature for the response transforms doesn't include the response object (or the config); only the lower level.

Comment: Your endpoint returns a response body with status 500?

Comment: Usually a http status code 500 means an exception occurred that was unexpected and unhandled. If the server knows what went wrong and needs to communicate that to the client, it shouldn't be a 500 response. Use the 4XX range to indicate something was wrong with the request. Use the 5XX range to indicate something went wrong on the server. If none of the defined codes fit, use a custom one that your client can then understand and handle gracefully. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: The server side has an unhandled exception handler which packages details about the problem as a json object (our odata endpoints structure it as an odata error object).  Most everything the server does is ajax apis, so that seemed to make the most sense.  A couple of apis return (when successful) a big bag o' bits like a pdf - but they can still have exceptions under certain conditions.  The callers are all still angular client calls.  Some of the devs got used to just tossing exceptions whenever they hit something they didn't like instead of crafting each http response as a result.

Comment: Details about the problem are useful to developers, but for users they're noise at best and a security concern at worst. Exceptions, handled or otherwise, are usually logged on the server, but the client is told as little as possible aka only as much as is necessary for the client to handle the failure gracefully.